# PHP double quote gets trimmed even when I tell it not to

Tags: php, string, csv, trim, double-quotes

I created a generic function on a utility class that converts comma-separated strings to an array. The function has an optional parameter on what to trim but defaults to trimming spaces and quotes (single and double).

```
public function convertToArray($string, $trim = " '\"") {
    $split = array();

    if(!empty($string)) {
        $split = str_getcsv($string, ",");

        if(!empty($trim)) {
            $split = array_map(function($split) use ($trim) {
                return trim($split, $trim);
            }, $split);
        }
    }

    echo var_dump($string);
    echo var_dump($trim);
    echo var_dump($split);

    return $split;
}
```

On a separate file I'm calling it like this (I only want to trim spaces and keep the quotes intact):

```
$utility->convertToArray($keywords, " ");
```

---

The output for the 3 `var_dump` are as follows:

#### $string

```
string(21) "Finance, "Accounting""
```

#### $trim

```
string(1) " "
```

#### $split

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "Finance"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "Accounting"
}
```

---

I expected to get `string(12) ""Accounting""` but somehow the double quote is being trimmed. The function works well with single quotes though since I get `string(12) "'Accounting'"`.

#### Additional Info

I'm using `str_getcsv` because the values could have commas within them and should not be split.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why not use `explode`, instead of `$split = str_getcsv($string, ",");`?

Comment: Have you looked at what str_getcsv does? because csv's can have quotes in them which are not part of the data.

Comment: `$split = str_getcsv($string, ",");` is what trims the double quotes by default

Comment: Ok thanks for pointing that out! Initially I was using `explode` but had to change it to `str_getcsv` because of a reason I forgot. Eventually my requirements changed and I forgot to revert it back to `explode`. Here's the related question I had for it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41286693/php-array-map-trim-parameters

Comment: @yivi Parsing CSV is slightly more complicate. Commas can be valid values as well, not only separators.

Comment: Álvaro, but he's not parsing csv. I think that's already established.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález and @yivi There you go, that's the reason why I wanted to use `str_getcsv`. It's because I have values like this: `"Language and/or Literature, Fiction"`

Comment: Then you stated your requirements incorrectly. Proposed solutions wont work, because everything is working as it should I guess.

Comment: @yivi You're right. In fact, we don't know the specs at all :)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález +1

Answer (score 1):

It happens that `str_getcsv()` will already remove the quotes:

```
$s = 'hello,"world"';
var_dump(str_getcsv($s, ','));

# array(2) {
#   [0] => string(2) "Hello"
#   [1] => string(5) "world"
# }
```

You could use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) instead:

```
$split = explode(',', $string);
```

Comment: Is there a way for me to keep using `str_getcsv` instead of `explode` because I have commas inside my values as well.

Comment: @uom-pgregorio as far as I known, this would not be possible with this function. The problem here lies in the whole CSV specification. Honestly, my recommendation is if you need to deal with data where commas and quotes are important, use a better format. Of course it is possible to make this current way work, it is always possible, just depends on the effort you want to put it. And it feels like this would be too much effort to resolve the side-effect of a problem and not its cause

Comment: how about regex? I'm open for it but I'm not good with regex.

Comment: @uom-pgregorio Checkout this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476744/exploding-a-string-using-a-regular-expression

Answer (score 1):

Use `explode` instead `str_getcsv`.

I think that will fix your troubles.

[str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-getcsv.php) will treat quotes as special "enclosure" delimiters, an remove them on its own.

[explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) is your friend.